# Predictive Uncertainty in classifiaction

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, uncertainty

I want to plot the predictive uncertainty for a binary classification problem. I have 30 observations and for each observation, I have 50 probability values predicted by the model. When I plot mean probability +/- one standard deviation for each observation, some of the bound goes below 0 or above 1 which does not make any sense actually. Is there any other way of obtaining the predictive uncertainty? [image: sample image of uncertainty visualization]

Comment: Interesting plot. Indeed, probabilities below 0 or above 1 don't make sense. Can you explain how you got these numbers?

Comment: All probabilities were between 0 and 1. I tried Monte Carlo dropout as suggested by Yarin Gal in his Ph.D. thesis paper. When I added 1 standard deviation of probability values with the mean of probabilities the bound goes below 0 or above 1. I got the probabilities by passing the data 50 times through the network during test time.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually meant something else - can you explain your setting a bit more? What kind of data do you have? What kind of model are you trying to build? How do you calculate these predicted probabilities and standard errors? To answer your question "Is there any other way...?" is difficult when we don't really know the current way :-)